# Intellij Idea - Toggle on/of "programming assists"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I start study for Oracle JavaSE certification exam.

I create an IntelliJ Idea project to handle my training source codes. I want to minimize the help from IntelliJ Idea.

I want to use only: color syntax, the terminal tab and the Idea project structure, git integration and disable all other fantastic Intellij programming assists, like auto complete, etc.

But somethimes I want to enable it quickly. Is there a way to enable / disable this kind of help as close to the toggle on / off way?

Comment: I recommend `BlueJ` for such situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File | Power Save Mode` seems appropriate, it disables error highlighting, auto-completion, background compilation.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is create your settings, and import/export as you want to toggle.

So for example, you could have one named "With assist" that has the settings enabled and go to `File->Export Settings...` to save it, then create a similar one for "Without assist."  Then as you want to toggle, you can use `File->Import Settings...` on the desired bundle of settings.

It's not exactly one click, but you can go to `Keymap` and search for `Import Settings` and `Export Settings` and assign shortcuts to them to make it easier too.